# I'm trying to pass an Object which contains an ArrayList and some other variables

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel, badparcelableexception

I'm trying to to pass a parcelable Object between two activities (a game activity and a pause screen activity) because i need to save and restore the position of the enemies on screen, the score and the timer. Now, when i did it i got the score and the timer, but not the enemies. I tweaked around a bit and found out that the bitmaps i had in the enemy classes could likely be a problem so i solved it with strings containing the bitmap location. Now i had a couple other things to sort out and it all came down to me making a Bundle and putting the parcelable object in said bundle, passing it to the other activity. Now, i only get `ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling` errors. This is the code i'm working with:

**First Activity** when pausing

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, PauseScreenActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
gameState = new GameState(new ArrayList<>(customGameView.getEnemies()), score, timeLeftInMillis, xPosition, yPosition);
b.putParcelable("gameState", gameState);
intent.putExtra("bundle", b);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Second Activity** retrieving the data

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
gameState = b.getParcelable("gameState");
```

**Second Activity** sending back the data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PauseScreenActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("gameState", gameState);
intent.putExtra("bundle", b);
startActivity(intent);
```

**First Activity** retrieving the data

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
gameState = b.getParcelable("gameState");
```

Now the errors are coming from the second activity's onCreate with the `b.getParcelable("gameState");`. I'll appreciate all the help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the `GameState` class look like?

Comment: Have you made the 'Enemy' Class parcelable as well? Because parceling requires all the sub classes of that class to be parcelable as well.

Comment: Yes, the Enemy class is parcelable as well. I'll post the GameState class as soon as i get back home.

Comment: please post the exception and stack trace in your question, as well as your code to read and write the `Parcel` from `GameState`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bundle#getParcelable docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#getParcelable(java.lang.String))

> Note: if the expected value is not a class provided by the Android platform, you must call `setClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader)` with the proper `ClassLoader` first. **Otherwise, this method might throw an exception** or return `null`.

The way I've always seen people recommend (which is a bit less complicated than messing with ClassLoaders!) is to just set it as an Extra on the Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, PauseScreenActivity.class);
gameState = new GameState(new ArrayList<>(customGameView.getEnemies()), score, timeLeftInMillis, xPosition, yPosition);
intent.putExtra("gameState", gameState);
startActivity(intent);
```

and then to unparcel it

```
gameState = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("gameState");
```

which is [much more friendly](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String))

If that doesn't work you might want to post your `GameState` class and the stack trace from the exception so people can see what's up

Comment: I already tried with the setExtra on the intent with the parcelable, not the bundle, and then unparcel it. The problem is that i get the classnotfound when unparceling in the second class. I'm trying to debug the thing and maybe go around it, but the GameState class is a class with an ArrayList<Enemy> (Enemy contains strings, ints, bools and floats), an int, a long and 2 floats.

Comment: I think you need to post the ``GameState`` class so people can check your parceling code, and the stack trace for the exception would help!